# How do I compile Android Browser (or other android-supplied applications)?

Tags: android

I want to add support for Arabic (or other languages which are currently unsupported) to the applications supplied by android platform (e.g. Browser) without the need of having root-access.

To add Arabic support (at least displaying only) in a ***normal application (using developer SDK***), I will need to:

1. Add fonts
2. Modify (reshape) the characters to be rendered
   For illustration, if I have string `a aaa`, I will need to change `a aaa` into `a bcd` because letter `a` at the beginning, middle, and end of a word need to be changed to `b`,`c` and `d` respectively)

But now I want to compile ***android's Browser (and other apps)***. I am planning to get the source codes for these applications and their dependencies and bundle them as stand-alone applications which do not require root-access, and thus do not void the warranty. Other solutions which void the warranty can be obtained [here](http://code.google.com/p/arabicandroid/downloads/list).

My Questions:

1. Is the application's (e.g. Browser's) source code + 'developer SDK' enough to accomplish this? Do I need to get the source code + the development environment for the android platform?
2. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the application's (e.g. Browser's)
>   source code + 'developer SDK' enough
>   to accomplish this?

No. The built-in applications can only be built as part of the firmware, as most were written before the SDK existed.

> Do I need to get the source code + the
>   development environment for the
>   android platform?

Yes.

Comment: Btw, does my plan seem to be feasible? --> pulling all dependencies from the OS and compile them into a stand alone app that does not require root access.

Comment: That depends on how many developers there are on your team. After all, you have quite a bit of code to rewrite, to get any such app to compile to the SDK, so you can distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

To add different localizations and formats you can use the resource files included with the application:

[Resources and Internationalization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html)